# Who wrote which comments in the 2001 edition of Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts-companion-book

I couldn't find a good answer anywhere else, and I can't find my copy of the 2001 edition either to confirm or cross reference handwriting.

The 2001 edition contains diegetic [scribbled notes](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them_(companion_book)#Comments_in_the_2001_edition) from characters in the series, namely Harry, Ron and Hermione.

One of which is initialled by Ron (in the section on Leprechauns):

> "but not mine. R. W."

Is there anyway to match the handwriting between other notes to attribute them to a character? Or is that not possible due to similar handwriting?

I don't think this is directly from the author as none of the handwritings in the book resemble [JKR's handwriting](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EUsax_sXkAAu_j9?format=jpg&name=large).

Comment: Is this asking in-universe or out-of-universe? Like do you want to know if it was JKR vs the book's designer, or are you asking which character they're meant to be ascribed to?

Comment: @ibid: let me know if I can make this sentence clearer: "Is there anyway to match the handwriting between other notes to attribute them to a character". If it's not obvious, it's which character they're meant to be ascribed to.

Comment: I think the answer then is a disappointing "no". They're all written in JKR's handwriting, and as far as I can tell there's no attempt made to use different styles for each character. You're meant to figure out from context, not from handwriting.

Comment: Looking through it again, it seems that there's a consistent style used to represent "Harry and Ron", though the two lines from Hermione are distinguished by being in cursive.

Comment: Also, none of the handwritings in the book resemble [JKR's handwriting](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EUsax_sXkAAu_j9?format=jpg&name=large).

Comment: I have it confirmed from the book's designer (Richard Horne) that the doodles are from JKR.

Comment: @ibid that would make a great answer if you can source the quote

Comment: That's why I asked above if you were looking for the in-universe writer or the out-of-universe writer.

Comment: @ibid I see where you're coming from now. I'm more interested in which character's each note related to. I had honestly assumed it was all written by JKR, so I thought you had meant they were by her *as* her, which is my mistake.

Comment: Would you accept an answer based on the French version of the book?

Comment: @falyna I can't say for certain but I wouldn't dismiss it out of hand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hermione only writes two lines on the "This book belongs to" page. She writes in full cursive.

Otherwise, Ron and Harry's handwritings are distinct throughout the rest of the book. Harry's writing is smaller and sort of half in cursive; Ron's is larger, messier, and basically not in cursive at all. There's also a noticeable distinction in how they form "y" and "g".

Sample:

Ron and Hermione:

[image]

Harry:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Ron:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice, I've never noticed that difference before. Going to have to give the book a fresh read now.

Comment: Great to see such a nice analysis based on evidence rather than just quotes, but I don't want to upvote because your rep is 3333 :-P